# how to display the vertical navigation in magento

Tags: magento

I am samiuddin. Few days back I started learning magento. I installed magento with sample data. I want to dispaly the categories on left side vertical navigation.

So I installed a vertical navigation extension from magento connect, but it is not displaying in the  frontend.

Please guide me.

Thanks and regards

MD.Samiuddin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There are many good people here who would love to help, but it is a bit hard to solve a problem with nothing to work off of.  Could you post some of your code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First change u r layout to 2 column leftbar

then check the xml file of that extension
find this

```
<block type="vertnav/navigation" name="catalog.vertnav" template="vertnav/left.phtml" before="-"/>
```

in that file and

place this in

```
<reference name="left"><block type="vertnav/navigation" name="catalog.vertnav" template="vertnav/left.phtml" before="-"/></reference>
```

hope this helps you.
if not we can discuss again

Answer (score 0):

To display vertical navigation in magento you need to install an extension like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html or you can also try many other available on magento connect.

Comment: Thnxs for your reply. I installed the vertical navigation extension, but it is not displaying. I need to change any configurations, please guide me.

Comment: Balu Mahesh is right. change the page layouts to 2 columns with leftbar that you want to display the vertical navigation on. Please tell us if you need help in changing layouts.